# How to use the platform's details instead of the connected account for Stripe connect

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to create a platform which will provide a digital service where the customers and connected accounts will be from around the world.  Clearly Stripe Connect is the Stripe product to use.

Because many of the connected accounts will be overseas this straight away rules out the use of transfers - unless I explored setting up separate platform accounts in the different overseas countries.  (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/capabilities-overview#cross-border-transfers)

So I am left with destination charges where I choose the connected account as the settlement merchant via the `on_behalf_of` parameter.  This means the charge goes against the connected account but I can still make money by charging an application fee.

As the connected account will be invisible to the end customer on the platform it seems inappropriate for the connected account's details to show on the customer's bank / credit card statement.  Instead I want the platform's details to show.

Stripe support have assured me it is possible to have only the platform's details.  Indeed this part of the API suggests I can control the statement descriptor which shows - https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-statement_descriptor

But another article - https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-statement_descriptor - seems to almost contradict this.  It explains

> Any additional information that’s displayed on a customer’s statement
>   is also provided by the same account that provides the static
>   component (business address, phone number).

Can anybody clarify?  Many thanks in advance.

**Update**

This article appears to settle the matter - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/connected-accounts

Guess I will just have to inform users on my website with a connected account that their details will show on the bank statement.

Comment: Destination Charges without `on_behalf_of` are using transfers, so they have the same rules regarding overseas transfers. While it is indeed possible to have the platform's details for Destination Charges, the key thing here is that you can't use them for overseas transactions.

Comment: You mean with `on_behalf_of` set on the destination charge there is no way of the platform's details showing?

Comment: Close to my meaning. With `on_behalf_of`, it's not possible to not have the connected account's details shown.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant haha.  But I think I'm right in saying I can still control the static component so it doesn't totally confuse the customer when they look at their bank statement.

Comment: Well, the static prefix comes from the connected account for `on_behalf_of`, but see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/statement-descriptors#dynamic-descriptors for setting the dynamic suffix.